# Firebase login failing

Tags: node.js, firebase

Has anyone experienced this and what might be the cause?
Have tried the following.... set "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0", export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0, but still not working.
Location: China

Error: Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth

Answer (score 0):

**Finally figured the problem out**

1. Find out if google products are allowed in your location, if no use a good VPN.
2. Turn off location.
3. Uninstall your node.js, restart your system and install again.
4. lastly, start this process again;
   -Install the latest version of (firebase-tools)
   [https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools] by running: sudo npm install -g
   firebase-tools to get the latest updates and bug fixes

   -Logout from your existing account by running firebase logout then login again
   to your account by running firebase login.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**I have two answers for you.**

Answer 1 : Your credentials are not valid All you need is to login again Try the command firebase login --reauth

Answer 2 : For such Authentication Error from Firebase CLI.

Do the below steps:

1. firebase logout
2. firebase login
3. Once the URL opens, go to Google account and remove access which was already given to firebase app distribution ["Remove Access"]
4. Come back to the URL window and select Allow
5. Should result in a successful login

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it didn't work. There is not even firebase access in my account.